# Action of Isometries on a Line in the Plane

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to determine the stabilizer of a line in a plane when acted upon by the group of isometries of the plane. Please note that I'm using the notation found in the Wikipedia article on [Euclidean plane isometries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_plane_isometry).

I've identified (and hopefully exhausted) the following isometries that will 'fix' a line $l$ **set-wise**. For the point-wise case, clearly only the identity transformation will work.

1. The identity transformation
2. Rotation about a point on the line by $\pi$ radians, i.e. $R_{c,\pi}$ for any point $c$ on the line $l$. I think this can also be expressed as $R_{c,\pi}=T_cR_{\pi}T_{-c}$
3. Translation in a direction parallel to the line, i.e. $T_v$ where $v$ is a vector parallel to $l$
4. Reflection about $l$ itself, i.e. $F_{\alpha,u}$ for any $\alpha$ lying on $l$, $u$ perpendicular to $l$
5. Reflection about any line perpendicular to $l$, i.e. $F_{\beta, v}$ for any $\beta$ in the plane, with $v$ parallel to $l$

I can't think of any more, but if I've missed any out, I'd be very grateful to learn of them. This leads me into my questions:

> How can I 'formally' express the response to the given question:
>
> The group G of isometries of the plane acts on the set of lines in the plane. Determine
> the stabilizer of a line in the plane.

Is there a better way of responding than just listing the isometries, as I have done here? i.e. Can we notate the set of the required isomteries more neatly?

Also,

> How can I express reflections of the form $F_{\gamma,w}$ for some point $\gamma$ and some vector $w$ in the plane in terms of translations by some vector, rotations about some point and reflections about the $e_1$ axis? I book I'm working through by Artin states that any isometry $m$ can be written in the form $m=T_aR_{0,\theta}$ or $m=T_aR_{0,\theta}r$ where $r$ is a reflection in the $e_1$ axis.

Many thanks to anyone who can help. Best,

Comment: My gut feeling is that this question is too elementary for this site, which is for questions of interest to research mathematicians. You might consider posting to math.stackexchange.com. If I were assigning this problem, I'd remark that isometries $f$ can be written in the form $f(x) = Mx + b$ for an orthogonal matrix $M$ and vector $b$, and remark that since the group acts transitively, we can choose any old line, say the $x$-axis, and see which $f$ fix this setwise. This puts restrictions on $M$ and $b$ (find them!). Any other stabilizer subgroup will conjugate to the one you just found. 

Comment: I disagree with "For the point-wise case, clearly only the identity transformation will work."  What about reflection in your line (item 4 on your list)?   

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing glide reflections. For any translation along a line you can reflect across the line getting a glide reflection. They are in the wikipedia article you sited.